# Resizing without DESTROYING the second partition of a disk

Tags: hard-drive, partition

I have a disk that was partitioned in two. The first partition was 1.8TB and is called TIME MACHINE. The second one was 1.2 TB and I call it TOSHIBA 1.2TB.

I would like to reduce the first partition to 1.2 TB and increase the second one to 1.8 TB.

I have managed to reduce the first one from 1.8 to 1.2, but disk utility will not let me increase the second one. Notice the gray space below the first partition. How do I increase the lower partition?

[image]

The TIME MACHINE partition was originally encrypted but I had to remove the encryption in order to test something. When I type `diskutil list` on terminal I get this for that disk:

```
/dev/disk2
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *3.0 TB     disk2
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk2s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS TIME MACHINE            1.2 TB     disk2s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Boot OS X               134.2 MB   disk2s3
   4:                  Apple_HFS TOSHIBA 1.2TB           1.2 TB     disk2s4
```

If possible I would like to delete this boot partition (because this is an external disk that I don't use to boot) and increase this toshiba partition to 1.8 TB.

Comment: What does *sudo gpt -r -vv show disk2* show in an OSX Terminal? Also look at *man diskutil* and search for *resizeVolume*. Another option is to turn on DebugMenu in Disk Utility to see hidden partitions like the 'Boot OS X' volume which is hidden. Based on your screen shot, your Recovery volume is hindering the resizing of Partition 4 (TOSHIBA 1.2TB).

Comment: It could be possible to decrypt a volume, yet still have core storage enabled. Does `diskutil cs list` show any core storage structures for the affected disk? Also, since this lists a much more narrow setup - non boot volume that was previously encrypted, I'd say we don't want this closed as duplicate of the general call for partitioning software. Good to link, but not really a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [iPartition](http://www.coriolis-systems.com/iPartition.php)

For all my partitioning, I use and recommend iPartition. It will allow you to resize partitions without deleting any data. It also works for Boot Camp volumes and other PC disks. It will automatically move partitions if necessary to allow resizing into free space that is located before the partition.

> With iPartition, resizing a partition is as simple as selecting it, grabbing the resize handle and dragging. Not only that, but if you have several operations to perform, iPartition lets you queue them up and run them one after another, so you can have a cup of coffee while iPartition works. This feature, coupled with iPartition’s ability to automatically rearrange your existing partitions when necessary, makes iPartition the easiest partitioning tool that you’ll ever use.
>
> [image]